# Samba open file permissions

Tags: networking, windows, samba

I have an open Samba share folder.  I would like to know the correct file permissions to allow users to create, edit, and delete files.

I tried 755, the problem I encountered was that users could create and delete files, but they could not rename files.

Comment: So you want created, edit, delete permissions. OK so far. What permissions do you _not_ want?

Answer (score 0):

The ability to rename files in a directory depends on the permissions of the directory itself - try setting the directory perms to `rwx`.

Comment: This is not necessarily true on a Samba share. Samba can be configured to provide inheritable permissions and other permissions that are a disjoint superset of the typical UNIX permissions mask, just like NTFS does.

Comment: Currently the folder(temp) is set to 777 which I am not comfortable with but I ran into the rename problem.  drwxrwxrwx.   TEMP